# How do I use Autoprefixer with Node.js

Tags: node.js, autoprefixer

According to the official documentation, this is simple:

Usage:

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-core');
var postcss      = require('postcss');

postcss([ autoprefixer ]).process(css).then(function (result) {
    result.warnings().forEach(function (warn) {
        console.warn(warn.toString());
    });
    console.log(result.css);
});
```

However, I'm confused as to what exactly I do to establish the object `css` to use with `process()`. I tried using the result of `fs.readfile()` but it doesn't seem to be working. My server module is fairly large, and it might be better to leave out code here. I really just simply need to know how to create `css` for the process function.

Comment: If it's really holding you up, instead of a bounty, did you bother asking over on https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer-core?

Comment: why on earth would you wait? Just ask there as well, and whoever answers you first *solves you problem*. Your problem isn't dependent on Stackoverflow, it's dependent on you =)

Comment: no, it's just that Stackoverflow is here to help answer questions, and the very first rule on the ["how to ask a question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page is "search, and research", so if you've not already asked this in the most authoritative place you should probably be asking, you didn't uphold your part of the bargain yet - you search and research, and when that yields no answer, you ask on Stackoverflow, tell us what you tried already and where you've looked, and then we try to help out. Especially in this case, it seems silly to offer a bounty this early in your problem.

Comment: Right, so my point in my first reply was to do both. Rather than posting to SO and then waiting for an answer and slapping a bounty on it to get a fast answer, explore the other avenues still open to you. If you do get an answer outside of SO (or you figure it out yourself), then *you* can write the answer (like you did), and can mark it as correct, so that future users can find it. Especially for open source projects, don't just ask on SO, also ask the people running those projects, and then put the link to that in your post so people know you're exploring all your options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've solved your issue.

You want to read a file into a variable called `css` and pass `css` to `process()`. The problem lies in which method you use to read the contents of the file.

Currently, you use `fs.readFile` which is asynchronous. You are using it as if it were synchronous. Therefore, you have two options:

Use [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) the way it is intended to be used, aka: asynchronously:

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-core');
var postcss      = require('postcss');

function processCSS(file, cb){

  fs.readFile(file, {encoding: String}, function (err, css) { 
      if (err) throw err;
      postcss([ autoprefixer ]).process(css).then(function (result) {
          result.warnings().forEach(function (warn) {
              console.warn(warn.toString());
          });
          console.log(result.css);
          cb( result.css );
      });
  });

}
```

If you decide to use this, it might be a good idea to learn about [promises](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks/), which can clean up async code.

Or instead of `fs.readFile`, you can use [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) which will read the file synchronously. Depending on how large your file is, this isn't the best idea.

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-core'); 
var postcss      = require('postcss');

function processCSS(file, cb){

  var css = fs.readFileSync(file, {encoding: String});
  postcss([ autoprefixer ]).process(css).then(function (result) {
      result.warnings().forEach(function (warn) {
          console.warn(warn.toString());
      });
      console.log(result.css);
      cb( result.css );
  });

}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: css **is** the result of `fs.readFile()`.

Silly mistake on my part. I tried to use the function that they show in the docs, and returned the result of it back to being handled by the file server before the `postcss()`function (async) had completed.